# MassUpdate with calculation and rounding

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table column that I want to do a calculating with 2 table fields and a bind parameter.

```
id | transaction_id | local_price | supplier_price | discrepancy
```

I want to calculate

> discrepancy = (supplier_price - local_price) / $count

(and `supplier_price` and `local_price` values are in the table. The **`discrepancy` should be in INT**.

So I wrote this php function

```
$cases = [];
$ids = [];
$params = [];
$discrepancyParam = [];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
     $transactionId = $value['transaction_id'];
     $cases[] = "WHEN {$transactionId} then ?";
     $ids[] = $transactionId;
     $params[] = "ceil((supplier_price-local_price)/" . $value['count'] . ")";
 }

$ids = implode(',', $ids);
$cases = implode(' ', $cases);

\DB::update("UPDATE accounting SET `discrepancy` = CASE `transaction_id` {$cases} END WHERE `transaction_id` in ({$ids})", $params);
```

This generates

> UPDATE accounting SET `discrepancy` = CASE `transaction_id` WHEN 37801 then ceil((supplier_price-local_price)/27) WHEN 37874 then ceil((supplier_price-local_price)/21) ... END WHERE `transaction_id` in (37801,37874,...)

But I get an error:

> General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'ceil((supplier_price-local_price)/27)' for column 'discrepancy' at row 14195

I think I am doing wrong with my query but I couldn't figure out what.

**Update**

I took only 1 element from each array and it showed this query:

> General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'ceil(`ups_price`-`local_price`)' for column 'discrepancy' at row 14195 (SQL: UPDATE accounting SET `discrepancy` = CASE `transaction_id` WHEN 37801 then ceil(`supplier_price`-`local_price`) END WHERE `transaction_id` in (37801))

So I took it and run in MySQLWorkbench

```
UPDATE accounting SET `discrepancy` = CASE `transaction_id` WHEN 37801 then ceil(`supplier_price`-`local_price`) END WHERE `transaction_id` in (37801)
```

Putting this in MySQLWorkbench works however in my code it doesn't.

I suspect it should be something related with my way of calling the DB fields in php

---

**Update 2**:

Even this doesn't work although `supplier_price` is INT for surely. It's definitely calling table field in php

```
These throw same error:
$params[] = "supplier_price";
$params[] = "`supplier_price`";
```

Comment: What is in `$value['count']`?

Comment: Just an integer

Comment: But where does it come from?

Comment: From `$array` which has lists of `['transaction_id', 'count']`. I have dumped my `$params`, everything seems variation of `ceil((supplier_price-local_price)/27)`

Comment: think the prices as bulk price in the shipment of X number of packages, discrepancy is per package

Comment: What I was trying to get at is that you can probably merge the query that produced `$array` with this `UPDATE` query and simplify things considerably.

Comment: The data is came from a CSV and processed :( And the pricing are in the database already (not came from csv) - this is the last step actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to bind a formula to a prepared query placeholder, which is not allowed; you can only bind values, so your `ceil((supplier_price-local_price)/21)` is being treated as a string, which is an illegal value for an integer column. If you want to protect against injection from this query, you need to only use placeholders for the `transaction_id` and `count` values, so you must include most of the formula in the query. This should work:

```
$params = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
     $transactionId = $value['transaction_id'];
     $cases[] = "WHEN ? then ceil((supplier_price-local_price)/?)";
     $ids[] = '?';
     $transaction_ids[] = $transactionId;
     array_push($params, $transactionId, $value['count']);
 }
$params = array_merge($params, $transaction_ids);
$ids = implode(',', $ids);
$cases = implode(' ', $cases);
\DB::update("UPDATE accounting SET `discrepancy` = CASE `transaction_id` {$cases} END WHERE `transaction_id` in ({$ids})", $params);
```

Comment: In this case, wouldn't `$ids` be `"?, ?, ?..."`? You should use `$transaction_ids` i think in the query

Comment: @senty yes, that is why I am collecting all the transaction id values in `$transaction_ids` and then merging that with `$params` to provide values for all those placeholders. This code basically completely protects you against injection, where your original code only protects from injection from the `count` values.

Comment: @senty here's a small demo of the code in operation: https://3v4l.org/VOsvF

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you either have null or incorrect value in `suppier_price` or `local_price`, it might be going negative or something? and you might have signed field for discrepancy. In all and all it is your data error. at row `14195`

Comment: It's the first value in my array. Makes me suspect that it's the code which has problem - `ceil((28962-24235)/27)` should return an integer right?

Comment: It's not it man. I think it's my way of putting calling fields in php because when I try the query in MysqlWorkbench, it works